# Changing A value on Time Column with Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that contains +10K rows, first 4 rows is image below:

[image]

As you can see the hour can be different, and I am trying to replace only hour value to "00" by 'for' loop, but it takes a quiet time. Code is:

```
for i in range(0,len(task_df)):
    task_df["TARGET_END_DATE"].iloc[i]=pd.datetime(year=task_df["TARGET_END_DATE"].iloc[i].year,
                                                month=task_df["TARGET_END_DATE"].iloc[i].month,
                                                day=task_df["TARGET_END_DATE"].iloc[i].day,
                                                hour=0,
                                                minute=0)
```

Is there any quicker way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need only `00` hours solution is simplier/ faster with [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html)    :

```
task_df["TARGET_END_DATE"] = task_df["TARGET_END_DATE"].dt.floor('d')
```

If need some hour, e.g. `10:00` add it:

```
task_df["TARGET_END_DATE"] = (task_df["TARGET_END_DATE"].dt.floor('d') + 
                                pd.Timedelta(10, 'hour'))
```

Comment: second recommendation is useful, hope dont forget. thnx

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
task_df["TARGET_END_DATE"].dt.normalize()
```